# How to parse JSON array without any object in Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am working with Retrofit and GSON. I have a JSON response as a JSON array but I don't know how to parse it by using a model class. My response is as follows:

```
[
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Four",
    "Five",
    "Six",
    "Seven",
    "Eight"
]
```

Comment: Is it a simple String array?

Comment: @DevrimTuncer yes ,but this response from retrofit.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just call in the callback a list of Strings and it should do the job...

```
new Callback<List<String>>().
```