# How to read nested JSON arrays with Retrofit and Jackson?

Tags: android, arrays, json, jackson, retrofit

In my Android application I use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to describe the internal API:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
ProductsService provideProductsService() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
        PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    RestAdapter.Builder restAdapterBuilder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setConverter(new JacksonConverter(objectMapper));
    return restAdapterBuilder
        .setEndpoint(Endpoints.newFixedEndpoint("http://192.168.1.1"))
        .build()
        .create(ProductsService.class);
```

In order to read *ProductLevels* I created the following interface:

```
public interface ProductsService {

    @GET("/api/products/{productId}/levels/")
    public Observable<List<ReadProductLevelsResponse>> readProductLevels(
            @Path("productId") int productId
    );

}
```

Here is the JSON string which is served by the backend:

```
[
    [
        1427378400000,
        553
    ],
    [
        1427382000000,
        553
    ]
]
```

When I try to read the JSON data in the empty *ReadProductLevelsResponse* class the following error occurs:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of ReadProductLevelsResponse out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: retrofit.ExceptionCatchingTypedInput$ExceptionCatchingInputStream@11ae0f16; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])

How can I read the JSON data into the *ReadProductLevelsResponse* class?

Comment: did you try @GET("/api/products/{productId}/levels/")
    public Observable<List<List<ReadProductLevelsResponse>>> readProductLevels(
            @Path("productId") int productId
    );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28630600/356895) that I have to use `List<List<Double>>` as the response type.

```
public interface ProductsService {

    @GET("/api/products/{productId}/levels/")
    public Observable<List<List<Double>>> readProductLevels(
            @Path("productId") int productId
    );

}
```

Follow up question: [How to transform a nested list of double values into a Java class using RxJava?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948117/how-to-transform-a-nested-list-of-double-into-a-java-class)