# Parse JSON String Using Retrofit, & Populate to List view/Recycler view?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, json-api

I am new to **Retrofit** and Android, and now i am stuck at receiving the **JSON** from **API**.

I want full solution to parse this JSON and populate it into RecyclerView or ListView.

The Sample of **JSON Data** is below:

```
["C","Python","Swift","Ruby","Javascript","PHP","C#","Java"]
```

Comment: call<ArrayList<String>> yourMethod();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your Retrofit interface:

```
@GET("api/programming_languages")
Call<List<String>> getLanguagesList();
```

And use it like this:

```
Call<List<String>> languagesCall = service.getLanguagesList();
languagesCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<String>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<List<String>> response) {
        List<String> languages = response.body();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

There are many other tutorials for Retrofit 2.0 so go and find something.

Comment: languagesCall.enqueue(new Callback<Model>()                                                  what should I use on <Model>, I don't have model of this json. I was unable  to make a model class using [link] (http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) .                                                         URL for this JSON is : http://api.technorio.com/tags                                   I am waiting for your help @reaven

Comment: It should be "List<String>" as well. I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes it parse the String but how do I populate this into RecyclerView?             @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TagAdapter.Tag_ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tagName.setText(Tags.get(position). How do I Get That Value);
    }

Answer (score 0):

They have the full documentation here https://square.github.io/retrofit/ Also you cannot have a json with ["", "", ""] format. What you can have is a format like [{"language":"C"},{"language":"Python"}.... etc ] and parse them using a CustomAdapter for List/RecyclerView. Using an ArrayList or ArrayList

Comment: Yes, there exist ["", ""] type of JSON and can be parsed using retrofit. You can look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628513/how-to-parse-json-array-without-any-object-in-retrofit

Comment: Its a simple string array, you cannot have that format of response if you want to map your values out, if not then feel free to use it.

Answer (score 0):

For eg your api is:
 @GET("/programming_languages")
Call> groupList();

Then after calling the groupList() method you should get the response as expected.

Comment: Can you please tell me more on detail. now I am Using  @GET("/tags")
    Call<Tag> tags();

Comment: check the code Call<String> call = groupList();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        
            public void onResponse(Call<String>call, Response<String> response) { Log.d(TAG, response.body().toString());
          
            }

        
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
               
            }
        });

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hemraj.technorio_posts/com.example.hemraj.technorio_posts.activity.TagActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for interface retrofit2.Call for method ApiInterface.groupList

Comment: I think Call<Tag> is incorrect, try Call<String> instead.