# How to parse get roles value from this json?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

Here is json response.

```
{
  "roles": [
    "merchant"
  ]
}
```

I am using retrofit and gson. How to get the value of roles? Currently I'm getting this error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON array without any object in Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628513/how-to-parse-json-array-without-any-object-in-retrofit)

Comment: Share your pojo class that used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your pojo class should be like this.then it will work

```
public class MyPojo
 {
private String[] roles;

public String[] getRoles ()
{
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles (String[] roles)
{
    this.roles = roles;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [roles = "+roles+"]";
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I use your code and it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an idea that everytime roles will be JsonArray, then directly you can use Arraylist in your pojo class, but if the roles is unknown whether it will come JsonObject or JsonArray, then you must use it as JsonElement in your Pojo like:

```
private JsonElement roles;

public JsonElement getRoles (){
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles (JsonElement roles){
    this.roles = roles;
}
```

After pojo creation you can convert your jsonelement by checking if the jsonelement is instance of Object or Array using

```
if(roles instanceof JsonObject)
```

Then convert using Gson accordingly.

Happy Coding!!